# Data incorreta no retorno do json

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

Boa tarde,

O retorno do Json traz a data mal formatada = "/Date(1420077600000)/", como tratar ?

```
{"TB1":1,"DTADMISSAO":"\/Date(1420077600000)\/"}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Esse é o trecho onde seto o campo Data:**

```
$.ajax({
                        url: "ObterFuncionario",
                        type: "post",
                        datatype: "json",
                        contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
                        processData: false,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#divCarregando").show();
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $("#divCarregando").hide();
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            $("#DTADMISSAO").val(data.DTADMISSAO);    
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert(result.responseText);
                        }
                    });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group small">
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            ADMISSÃO:
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" id="DTADMISSAO" class="form-control input-sm" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Como você está populando o valor no campo?

Comment: Acrescentei na pergunta o trecho de código que popula o campo.

Comment: Poste o código do controller do MVC que você está passando a data.

Comment: o campo que voce esta retornando pro json é um Datetime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem essa "solução de contorno".

```
var dataAdmissao = obj.DTADMISSAO
var milisegundos = parseInt(dataAdmissao.slice(dataAdmissao.indexOf('(') + 1, dataAdmissao.indexOf(')')));
var data = new Date(milisegundos);
```

Com certeza tem algum jeito muito melhor de fazer isso.

Caso não encontre nenhuma solução, talvez sirva.

Comment: Filipe funcionou + ou -, como faço pra formatar ? tá retornando assim: Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0200 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Comment: @AdrianoCordeiro, se você estiver usando o `DatePicker`, pode usar dessa forma `$.datepicker.formatDate('seu-formato-aqui', data);`. Caso contrário, pode formatar na mão pegando as partes da data assim: `data.getMonth()`, `data.getDate()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Esse valor que está dentro do Date() é o número de milissegundos desde meia-noite de 1 de Janeiro de 1970.

Você pode converter pra Data novamente criando uma nova data com esse valor:

```
function retornaData(valor){
    var dataAdmissao = valor;
    var milisegundos = parseInt(dataAdmissao.slice(dataAdmissao.indexOf('(') + 1, dataAdmissao.indexOf(')')));
    var data = new Date(milisegundos);

    return (("0" + (data.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" +  ("0" + (data.getDate())).slice(-2) + "/" + data.getFullYear())
}
```

Uso:

```
$("#DTADMISSAO").val(retornaData(data.DTADMISSAO));
```

Exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/g5n300ud/1/

Referências: [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime), [getTime (Date) (JavaScript)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/7hcawkw2(v=vs.94).aspx)

Comment: Oi Laerte dá erro: "Invalid Date"

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

No retorno da sua data você pode converter ela para `ToShortDateString`, ai no success do seu ajax ela ja vem formatada

Exempo:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Faça essa alteração no retorno da Controller**

Exemplo:

```css
public ActionResult RetornarData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request) {
  DateTime data=DateTime.Now;
  return Json(data.ToString(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```