# Serializar/Deserializar DateTime

Tags: c#, arquivo, stream

Estou salvando em arquivo texto um objeto serializado que contém apenas campos do tipo DateTime, porém, a data está salvando de forma errada.

Vou demonstrar com um exemplo o que estou fazendo.

Meu objeto DataBaseViewModel cotém dois campos do tipo DateTime

```
[Serializable]
public class DataBaseViewModel
{
    public DateTime ultimaAtualizacaoTfs { get; set; }
    public DateTime ultimaAtualizacaoSis { get; set; }
}
```

Adiciono valores ao meu objeto

```
var datasBase = new DatasBaseViewModel();
datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoSis = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 10, 10);
datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoTfs = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 11, 11);
```

Então salvo o objeto serializado em texto

```
using (Stream stream = File.Open(_pathToDatasBase, FileMode.Create))
using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    streamWriter.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataBase));
}
```

Em outro momento, vou ler o conteúdo do meu arquivo de texto.

```
var datasBase = new DataBaseViewModel();
using (Stream stream = File.Open(_pathToDatasBase, FileMode.Open))
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    datasBase = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DataBaseViewModel>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Após ler e deserializar, meu objeto está com a data incorreta, diferente do que eu salvei.

Nesse caso, salvei as datas `09/11/2015 15:10:10` e `09/11/2015 15:11:11` e no objeto deserializado tenho as datas `09/11/2015 17:10:10` e `09/11/2015 17:11:11`.

O arquivo de texto com o objeto serializado está salvo dessa maneira:

```
{"ultimaAtualizacaoTfs":"\/Date(1447089071000)\/","ultimaAtualizacaoSis":"\/Date(1447089010000)\/"}
```

Comment: Certamente é problema de fuso horário. Para saber porque precisaria ver mais contexto. Não sei se estou perdendo alguma coisa, mas se você salva de um jeito e lê igual, não deveria dar problema.

Comment: Deve esta usando utc date...  tente alterar  `new StreamReader(stream,Encoding.UTF8))`

Comment: Tem essa resposta aqui que talvez possa te ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93931/data-incorreta-no-retorno-do-json/93941#93941

Comment: Exatamente @bigown. Estou salvando UTC-2 (local) e deserializando UTC. Converti a data no momento que a leio: datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoTfs.ToLocalTime()

Comment: No seu código não tem conversão alguma. Eu acho que o problema está em outro lugar e sem postar algo que dê pra gente ver e testar, fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: O código é somente isso mesmo, acho que na hora de deserializar deve assumir que é UTC, pois em momento algum antes de salvar eu altero o fuso.

Comment: Pode ser, por isso que eu acho que toda data deveria ser UTC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você mudar o tipo das duas propriedades da sua classe para `DateTimeOffset` você vai ser em debug que no final do valor ele vai estar com -2, ao descerializar o objeto e olhar o mesmo valor na nova classe o valor vai estar 0, são exatamente as duas horas que estão aumentando.

Basta mudar a forma como você cria a data que ele vai funcionar normal.

```html
            datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoTfs = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 10, 10,  DateTimeKind.Utc);
            datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoSis = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 11, 11, DateTimeKind.Utc
```

Também vai notar que o valor serializado é diferente agora, porque ele está colocando a data com o valor correto.

Não precisa mudar o valor das propriedades para `DateTimeOffset`, só se tiver curiosidade de ver a diferença que falei. Ele funciona normal com `DateTime`

```js
            var dataCerta = new DateTime();
            var dataErrada = new DateTime();

            dataCerta = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 10, 10,  DateTimeKind.Utc);
            dataErrada = new DateTime(2015, 11, 9, 15, 10, 10);


            var dataCertaSerializada = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataCerta);
            var dataErradaSerializada = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(dataErrada);

            Console.Write(String.Format("Valor serializado da data certa:  {0} \n", dataCertaSerializada.ToString()));
            Console.Write(String.Format("Valor serializado da data errada: {0} \n", dataErradaSerializada.ToString()));

            var dataCertaDecerializada = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTime>(dataCertaSerializada);
            var dataErradaDecerializada = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<DateTime>(dataErradaSerializada);

            Console.Write(String.Format("Valor Deserializado da data certa:  {0} \n", dataCertaDecerializada.ToString()));
            Console.Write(String.Format("Valor Deserializado da data errada: {0} \n", dataErradaDecerializada.ToString()));
```

Comment: Valeu @Ricardo. Fiz a conversão no momento da leitura também, caso queira complementar sua resposta _datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoTfs = datasBase.ultimaAtualizacaoTfs.ToLocalTime();_ Ambas funcionam.